# "SQLite Version Error"

Tags: firefox, selenium, sqlite, osx-snow-leopard

I tried to run webrat tests in selenium mode, but I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Security requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides version 1.0.0
```

I followed the solution here “http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/?p=105", then I got another error when selenium tried to open firefox:

```
SQLite Version Error
The application has been updated, but your version of SQLite is too old and the application cannot run.
```

I am on Snow Leopard.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you (it didn't for me because the JIRA claims that everything is fixed in the newest versions and they removed the snow-leopard.patch...) then try to move the Firefox dylib out of the way - so do the mv but NOT the cp as described at the agilesoftwaretesting.com link.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to change the SQLite Firefox ships with.  The [Selenium ticket for this describes the proper fix for it](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-743).